# Rich Text Editor Not Showing Content on Edit

Tags: 2013, rich-text

I have a rich text editor which can create content just fine. When I go to edit the content, nothing shows up in the text area.

Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Check is your field set with option "Append Changes to Existing Text " to "Yes"?

Comment: Which browser are you using? try with Internet explorer. The rich text options appears when you hover OR start typing in Rich text boxes. Pls try doing this